# Scroll Listview Items

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-2.0

I want to scroll the items on the listview on the event of a button clik.is there any function  on .Net(Windows Application) for this?

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about the WPF Listview? Then the following methods
may help you:

ListView.BringIntoView
ListView.ScrollIntoView

You can find information about these methods at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview_members.aspx

Or you could set the property SelectedIndex, e.g.:
ListView.SelectedIndex = ListView.SelectedIndex + 1;

The last possibility i can imagine is to make the mousewheel-event of the listview fire, but i guess this is not recommended because WPF-Controls are lookless...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But my system is a Touch Screen system on a shop.There is no mouse.Every thing is doing by fingure.Also im not using WPF, :(

Comment: Also By chnging the selected index i could chnge the selected index,but the listview is not scrolling :(

Answer (score 0):

The most popular way is [SendKeys Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(VS.85).aspx).
You must set a focus to your ListView and use SendKeys method. Then you can return focus to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in WinForms:

```
ListView1.Items(newIndex).EnsureVisible()
```

You'd have to calculate newIndex so that it scrolled a suitable amount of rows.